# How to implement a drop target for the SWT browser widget

Tags: browser, swt, drag-and-drop

How to implement a drop target for the SWT browser widget? Taking a 
Browser instance as parameter to the `DropTarget` constructor causes no 
notification of any registered drop listeners.

```
    Browser browser = new Browser(parent, SWT.NONE); 
    int operations = DND.DROP_MOVE | DND.DROP_COPY | DND.DROP_DEFAULT; 
    DropTarget target = new DropTarget(browser, operations); 
    target.setTransfer(...) 
    DropTargetListener listener = ...; 
    target.addDropListener(listener);
```

Thanks, 
Henry

Answer (score 0):

I think that's not easily possible since the Browser are a collection of native widgets as well, see this: http://dev.eclipse.org/mhonarc/lists/platform-swt-dev/msg04523.html

Two workarounds come to my mind:

- Do it in HTML5, there is DND support
- The hacky solution: on MouseOver create a transparent, display an invisible shell that sits directly over the browser and takes the Drop.